# MYSQL - Select query with multiple OR conditions is Slow

Tags: mysql, select, optimization

I have a table of over 2 million rows and i need to rapidly do select queries on it in a loop.

```
SELECT ID,WebSite FROM `CompanyData` WHERE A1='data1' OR A2='data2' OR A3='data3'
```

It's taking 300 milli-seconds. I feel it shouldn't take this much time. Here is the EXPLAIN from that query:

```
--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table    | type  | possible_keys  | key      |  key_len    | ref  | rows  | Extra                              |
+----+-------------+----------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+-------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE     | CompanyData | index | A1,A2,A3     | A1,A2,A3 | 153,153,153 | NULL | 3     | Using union(A1,A2,A3); Using where |
+----+-------------+----------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+-------------------------------------------+
```

Here is the table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `CompanyData` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `WebSite` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CompanyName` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `A1` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  `A2` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  `A3` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `WebSite` (`WebSite`,`CompanyName`),
  KEY `CompanyName` (`CompanyName`),
  KEY `A1` (`A1`),
  KEY `A2` (`A2`),
  KEY `A3` (`A3`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3931223 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Recently i have inserted another 10 million records to the table. Then the same 
Query is taking around 3 Seconds.

Please suggest a way to improve the Select query lookup. Even I am ready to restructure the table.

Thanks

Comment: The general suggestion is to change the query and use union instead of series of ORs. However, the explain seems to suggest that mysql optimised your query already from this aspect, but it does not hurt to try it out.

Comment: add a composite key:  KEY `AX` (`A1`,`A2`,`A3`). Mysql can only use one key.

Comment: That is not going to help! Mysql would not be able to use the composite key to satisfy the `OR A2='data2' OR A3='data3'` criteria because each criterion relates to a single field only and a composite key can only be used for looking up a single field if that single field is the leftmost one in the index.

Comment: No one ever needs to do queries 'in a loop'. I think the problem's right there!

Answer (score 6):

It is difficult for MySQL to optimize conditions with an `OR`.  You might be better trying:

```
SELECT ID, WebSite
FROM `CompanyData`
WHERE A1 = 'data1'
UNION
SELECT ID, WebSite
FROM `CompanyData`
WHERE A2 = 'data2' 
UNION
SELECT ID, WebSite
FROM `CompanyData`
WHERE A3 = 'data3';
```

Note that this uses `UNION` instead of `UNION ALL`.  An alternative version with `UNION ALL` looks like this (assuming the values are never `NULL`):

```
SELECT ID, WebSite
FROM `CompanyData`
WHERE A1 = 'data1'
UNION ALL
SELECT ID, WebSite
FROM `CompanyData`
WHERE A2 = 'data2' AND A1 <> 'data1'
UNION ALL
SELECT ID, WebSite
FROM `CompanyData`
WHERE A3 = 'data3' AND A1 <> 'data1' AND A2 <> 'data2';
```

For this query, the best indexes are composite indexes:  `(A1, ID, WebSite)`, `(A2, A1, ID, Website)`, and `(A3, A1, A2, ID, WebSite)`.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays splayed across columns are problematical.

Give this a try...

```
CREATE TABLE `CompanyData` (
    `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    `WebSite` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL, 
    `CompanyName` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (`ID`), 
    UNIQUE KEY `WebSite` (`WebSite`,`CompanyName`), 
    KEY `CompanyName` (`CompanyName`), 
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
CREATE TABLE `Stuff` (
    `CompanyID` int(11) NOT NULL
    `A` varchar(150) NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (A, CompanyID)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

SELECT  c.ID, c.WebSite
    FROM  CompanyData AS c
    JOIN  Stuff AS s ON c.ID = s.CompanyID
    WHERE  s.A IN ('data1', 'data2', 'data3');
```